# How to replace a multiple patterns in the same string using regex and javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

i want to replace multiple patterns in the same string using regex and javascript.

What i am trying to do?
i have a string for example

```
string = "hello i am [12@fname lname] and i am referring this user [23@fname1 lname1]"
```

now i get all the strings with [] using regex

```
const get_strings_in_brackets = string.match(/\[(\d+@[\w\s]+)]/g);
```

so get_strings_in_brackets will have
["[12@fname lname]", "[23@fname1 lname1]"]

now i want these to be replaced with string `"<some-tag id="12"/>` `"<some-tag id="23"/>` in the string `"hello i am [12@fname lname] and i am referring this user [23@fname1 lname1]"`

also this number 12 in this string `"<some-tag id="12"/>` is got from the string `["[12@fname lname]"` before @ character.

What i have tried to do?

i have tried to replace for only one string withing brackets meaning for the example below 
    string ="hello i am [12@fname lname1]"

```
const extracted_string_in_brackets = string.match(/\[(\d+@[\w\s]+)]/g);
const get_number_before_at_char = 
    extracted_string_in_brackets[0].substring(1, 
    extracted_string_in_brackets[0].indexOf('@'));
const string_to_add_in_tag = `<some-tag 
    id="${get_number_before_at_char}"/>`;
const final_string = string.replace(extracted_string_in_brackets, 
    string_to_add_in_tag);
```

The above code works if i have only one string within square brackets. But how do i do it with multiple strings in brackets and replacing that with tag string that is for example .

Could someone help me solve this. thanks.

Comment: Now, `final_string` is equal to `string`.  What is the expected output for `hello i am [12@fname lname] and i am referring this user [23@fname1 lname1]`? Please use backticks for the code, `\``

Comment: the expected output for the example string is hello i am <some-tag id="12"> and i am referring this user <some-tag id="23">. thanks

Comment: So, Georg's answer is the right way, but that pattern will lead to issues in case there are other brackets substrings that do not match your pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a group reference in your replacement:

```js
string = "hello i am [12@fname lname] and i am referring this user [23@fname1 lname1]"

newstr = string.replace(/\[(.+?)@(.+?)\]/g, '<some-tag id="$1"/>')

console.log(newstr)
```

Comment: If there is a `[substring]` with no `@` and then a `[...@...]`, `/\[(.+?)@(.+?)\]/g` will fail. Never rely on `.*` or `.+` when you need to make sure there is a `c` between `a` and `b`.

Comment: This answer would be better if you briefly explained what the reference is and what it's doing.  Most regular expressions already look like gobbledygook, so spelling out what's going on would likely help others.  It's worth at least calling attention to the `$1` and how it corresponds to the capturing group.

Comment: @Wyck:  feel free to edit my answer and add what you think is necessary.

Comment: This is a great answer!
Thanks @georg

Comment: @JorgeWanderSantanaUreña It is a [wrong answer](https://regex101.com/r/XsqhV1/1).

Comment: @georg Please either fix it or remove. You have misled a couple of people already that it is the solution.

Comment: but @WiktorStribiżew, this is at least, a good reference to have and continue building another similar way to reach the goal. Isn't it ?

Comment: @JorgeWanderSantanaUreña Not a code only answer with no explanation and no warning it may yield unexpected results.

Comment: Ok, i got you. But look at this case: You have passed a lot of hours trying to do something and you don't know what else to do, and you would like a least any small idea that help you to continue, anything. And after looking and looking, you finally see this answer. Maybe not perfect, but enough to continue exploring and reaching your goal.  xD just a thinking...